# Derivative of a summation (looking for the rule used)

Tags: summation

I was solving one problem, and I ended up with this derivative:

$$ \frac{\delta \frac{1}{10} (x_1 + \dots+x_i+\dots x_n) (x_i)}{\delta  x_i} = 15 $$

and from the answer key the end is (considering a symmetry between $x_i = x_j$):

$$ x = \frac{150}{(n+1)}$$

What rule was applied here? :)

Comment: take the limit of dxi/dxi as dxi ->0

Comment: are x1... xn constants?

Comment: @gebra yes they are

Comment: why does the sum have $x_i$ in the middle? does the sum go from $x_1$ to $x_n$ in counting order? Is $x_i$ also a constant?

Comment: @gebra I think it was placed in the question to emphasize that $x_i$ is part of the series. I figured out the answer though thanks to your question about whether the series are constants. :) I also posted the answer in this thread

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer:

$$ \frac{2x_i + \sum_{j \neq i}^n x_j}{10}= 15 $$
$$ 2x_i + \sum_{j \neq i}^n x_j= 150 $$
$$ x_i = \frac {150 - \sum_{j \neq i}^n x_j}{2}$$

by symmetry (stemming from the question), it can be set that $x_i = x_j$, therefore,

$$ 2x_i + \sum_{j = i}^n x_i  = 150 $$
by the rule of summation of constants,
$$ x_i + nx_i = 150$$ 
$$x_i = \frac{150}{1+n}$$

Comment: this seems reasonable. The problem i'm having is not the differentiation, it is the meaning of $x_i$ and what exactly the variables mean. I hope you can clarify this in the question